# Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s) in INSERT

Tags: mysql, sql, workbench

I'm trying to run this command

```
insert into supply_kit (processor_id, supply_id, amount) values (3, 1, 0);
```

to this table

[image: tables schema]

and get error: 
`insert into supply_kit (processor_id, supply_id, amount) values (3, 1, 0)   Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)    0.000 sec`

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You can't get that error from that query.

Comment: @Barmar but it's here. Idk why

Comment: That error comes from using a subquery that returns multiple columns in a place where a single value is expected.

Comment: You're really using hard-coded numbers in the `values` list, not a subquery?

Comment: Check the table for triggers.

Comment: @stickybit you right, I have one, but I don't know how to delete it. I delete trigger in EER Diagram tab and start forward engeneering, but it dosn't disappear in local instance tab

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/drop-trigger.html